# Extjs not working in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4.1

I am trying to develop a google app engine application with spring and extjs in the view. I have successfully setup spring-mvc. It is very simple, I have a home view webapps/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp and I have mapped webapps/resources/ as /resources. I have copied Extjs-4.1 js library to webapps/resources/extjs. I know the mapping is working, as I am able to navigate to the resources, writing the full path in the address field.

My home.jsp is very simple, including ext-all-debug.js and ext-all.css in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/extjs/extjs-all.js">
```

I know the path is right, as I can load it in the browser pasting the address in the address field.

The problem is that is not working. I have a script in my body to open an extjs alert, and it is never executed. I put a breakpoint in firebug and it never gets there and I don't get any error in the console. It is like it was ignoring the script tag.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The path `resources/..` is a path relative to the document. Use leading slash to make it relative to root folder: `/resources/..`